# Cannot infer the type of function in environment

Tags: coq

I am trying to implement binary decision diagrams in Coq. I want to create BDDs using 2CNF formulas.

First, the imports;

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.
Require Import Coq.Arith.EqNat.
Require Import Program.Wf.
```

For this, I have literals with a natural number to represent the order.

```
Inductive literal := 
  | L (val: nat).
```

Using this, I create the clauses.

```
Inductive two_clause := 
  Or (left: literal) (right: literal).
```

Next, I have the BDD and some functions on the BDD.

```
Inductive bdd := 
  | Vertex (L: literal) (left_edge: bdd) (right_edge: bdd)
  | Leaf (val: Prop).

Definition get_bdd_var (b: bdd) : option literal :=
  match b with
    | Vertex l _ _  => Some l
    | _             => None
  end.

Definition get_high (b: bdd) : bdd := 
  match b with 
    | Vertex _ h _  => h
    | Leaf v        => Leaf v
  end.

Definition get_low (b: bdd) : bdd := 
  match b with 
    | Vertex _ _ l  => l
    | Leaf v        => Leaf v
  end.
```

Lastly, I create the BDD with the recursive apply function (to keep it simple, I reduced the amount of cases, and only made the apply algorithm for the `and` case.

```
Definition construct (p: literal) (T U: option bdd) : option bdd := 
  match (T, U) with 
    | (Some T, Some U)  => Some (Vertex p T U)
    | _                 => None
  end.

Fixpoint bdd_size (b: bdd) : nat := 
  match b with 
    | Leaf _ => 0
    | Vertex _ l r => 1 + (bdd_size l) + (bdd_size r)
  end
.

Definition bdds_size (b1 b2: bdd) : nat := 
  bdd_size b1 + bdd_size b2.

Variable o_map : literal -> nat.

Fixpoint apply_and (T U : bdd) {bdds_size T U} : option bdd := 
  let tvaro := get_bdd_var T in
  let uvaro := get_bdd_var U in
  match (tvaro, uvaro) with
    | (Some tvar, Some uvar) =>  
      match (compare (o_map (tvar)) (o_map (uvar))) with 
        | Lt => construct
                  (tvar) 
                  (apply_and (get_high T: bdd) U)
                  (apply_and (get_low T: bdd) U)
        | _  => construct
                  (tvar)
                  (apply_and (get_high T:bdd) (get_high U:bdd))
                  (apply_and (get_low T:bdd) (get_low U:bdd))
      end 
    | _ => None
   end.
```

However, Coq is not convinced the apply function terminates. Therefore, I added the reducing argument that the size of T and U reduces.
However, I get the message that Coq cannot infer the type of `bdds_size`.

What do I need to change for this to work?

Comment: I added `Require Import Nat. Definition o_map (l : literal) : nat := match l with L n => n end.` to reproduce the error. Please edit these into the question if they provide the intended definitions of `compare` and `o_map`.

Comment: From a quick look, It seems that `get_high b` can be equal to `b`(if it is a `Leaf`). So the first recursive call within `apply_and` could, in principle, be the same as `apply_and T U`, thus leading to non-termination.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proximate problem with the code in the question is essentially a syntax error which leads to a misparse. `Fixpoint apply_and (T U : bdd) {bdds_size T U}` is being parsed as the start of a definition for `apply_and` which takes two explicit arguments `T` and `U` of type `bdd`, and then three implicit arguments `bdds_size`, `T`, and `U` with unspecified type. Because this is clearly not what you intended, any errors after that point become meaningless.

The fixpoint annotation, according to [the documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/inductive.html#grammar-token-fixannot), should be of one of the following three forms:

```
<fixannot> ::= { struct <ident> }
             | { wf <one_term> <ident> }
             | { measure <one_term> <ident>? <one_term>? }
```

Furthermore, the `wf` and `measure` forms can only be used with `Program Fixpoint`, rather than bare `Fixpoint`. The `struct` form doesn't look useful to us, because it expects one of the existing arguments to be decreasing, whereas we want to note that the expression `bdds_size T U` decreases. Therefore, we'll switch to `Program Fixpoint`, and use the `measure` form.

```
Program Fixpoint apply_and (T U : bdd) {measure (bdds_size T U)} : option bdd := 
  let tvaro := get_bdd_var T in
  let uvaro := get_bdd_var U in
  match (tvaro, uvaro) with
    | (Some tvar, Some uvar) =>  
      match (compare (o_map (tvar)) (o_map (uvar))) with 
        | Lt => construct
                  (tvar) 
                  (apply_and (get_high T) U)
                  (apply_and (get_low T) U)
        | _  => construct
                  (tvar)
                  (apply_and (get_high T) (get_high U))
                  (apply_and (get_low T) (get_low U))
      end 
    | _ => None
   end.
(* 8 obligations remaining *)
```

After that, you need to use the [`Program`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html) machinery, such as `Next Obligation.`, to handle each of the generated obligations.

However, as noted by Pierre Jouvelot in the comments, these obligations are not provable because `bdd_size (get_high (Leaf v)) < bdd_size (Leaf v)` is not true.